# Circular dependencies in CDK between lambda and step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a lambda that needs to execute a step function (in some cases)
and the same step function needs to invoke the same lambda (in that case it will not execute the step function again). both are in the same stack.

My workflow is like this: I create the lambda, then the step function with the lambda invocation,
then when I try to add the step function arn to the lambda environment or if I try to give the lambda the permission to execute the step function `my_sfn.grant_start_execution(my_lambda)` I get `Circular dependencies`

is there any way around it?

Comment: Sounds like it should be two separate lambdas, to be honest. Lambdas should be as small as possible.

Comment: @gshpychka yes, I am trying to avoid it.